# React fetching data based on previously fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want is to fetch all users and then based on the username I fetch movies they have watched. I'm still struggling to understand when a state gets changed, more often than not at the end movies is not in the right order, so that when the MovieInfo-Component gets the data the users get the wrong movies assigned.

My code:

```
export default class Admin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      movies: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://a-url/users/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            users: data.users,
          },
          () => {}
        );
        data.users.map((user) => this.fetchMovies(user.name));
      });
  }

  fetchMovies = (user) => {
    fetch('https://a-url/' + user + '/movies/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            movies: [...this.state.movies, ...[data.movies]],
          },
          () => {}
        );
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { users, movies } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className='wum__admin section__padding'>
        {users.length > 0 &&
        movies.length > 0 &&
        users.length === movies.length ? (
          <>
            {movies &&
              users &&
              users.map((user, i) => (
                <MovieInfo
                  key={i}
                  movies={movies[user.id - 1]}
                  id={user.id}
                  user={user.name}
                />
              ))}
          </>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using class components in 2022?

Comment: @mstephen19 I'm still learning the basics I didn't know you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to filter movies by user you could change the `movies` state to be an object where each property (`user.name`) will have its list of movies:

```
export default class Admin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      movies: {},
    };
  }

  ...

  fetchMovies = (user) => {
    fetch('https://a-url/' + user + '/movies/')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const newMovies = { ...this.state.movies };
        newMovies[user] = movies;
        this.setState(
          {
            movies: newMovies,
          },
          () => {}
        );
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { users, movies } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className='wum__admin section__padding'>
        {users.length > 0 &&
          users.map((user, i) => (
            <MovieInfo
              key={i}
              movies={movies[user.name]}
              id={user.id}
              user={user.name}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```